# php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade, server-setup, setup

when I install a new theme I do this commands via Putty:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

how can I fix this problem?
I'm working on Magento 2.1.0

> PHP Warning: Uncaught Exception: Warning: require(/var/www/vhosts/a.com/httpdocs/setup/config/application.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/a.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php on line 57 in /var/www/vhosts/a.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Comment: Please check,it may cause of permission.

Answer (score 3):

Your site miss the file `/var/www/vhosts/a.com/httpdocs/setup/config/application.config.php`, you could copy it from original official install files.

Also a possibility, the file `application.config.php` or the directory `/var/www/vhosts/a.com/httpdocs/setup/config/` lack permission, try to give it read and write permission.

Comment: setup  folder not in httpdocs

Comment: @Amd2030 `Setup folder not in httpdocs` indicates that your installation is **not complete**, please download again from official page https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: had this happen when cloning a site -  setup didn't copy for some reason. Upload the setup folder into the base - php bin/magento setup:upgrade > php bin/magento setup:di:compile > php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -s standard = problem fixed for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue; it happened to me because a `composer update` failed in the middle of its process and did not clean up correctly, leading to a corrupted vendor asset.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove your `vendor/` folder and reinstall vendor assets from `composer.lock`:

1. `rm -rf vendor/`
2. `composer install`

After running the above, `bin/magento set:up` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
first: setup folder not there so, i install a new and clear installation
```

```
second: my hosting use Plesk so all command should be with the path of php
```

the replacment code of

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

is

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also face this issue when setup:upgrade, if you not install magento properly then some files missing in root directories, so best option is download files from magento official side related your magento version.

And regarding your issue add `setup/config/application.config.php`
after check "app/" in all files and "etc/" in all files with magento default.
then

```
rm -rf var/page_cache/ var/cache/ pub/static/frontend/ generated/ && php bin/magento setup:upgrade  && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to manually copy any files from magento2-base/composer.json map-section to the magento root directory:

```
cat vendor/magento/magento2-base/composer.json | jq '.extra.map[][1]' | xargs -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'echo -n "{}"; if [ -d "vendor/magento/magento2-base/{}" ]; then echo -n "/"; fi; echo' | xargs -n1 -I'{}' rsync -a --delete 'vendor/magento/magento2-base/{}' '{}'
```

Answer (score -3):

Deleting manually

- var/generation
- var/cache
- var/view_preprocessed
- var/page_cache
- var/di

solved it for me.

or by using ssh you can run below commands

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/di/*
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: after run previous commands: # var/generation/*
    -bash: var/generation/Composer: Is a directory
 # var/view_preprocessed/*
    -bash: var/view_preprocessed/css: Is a directory
 # var/page_cache/*
    -bash: var/page_cache/mage--0: Is a directory
 # var/di/*
    -bash: var/di/adminhtml.ser: Permission denied

Comment: Hi, I have updated a script.

Comment: still not working

Comment: this doesn't work